# How to use a grep command in bourne shell script to search a new input paramter when there is space in between

Tags: shell, unix, grep, sh

I would like to search a pattern input by the user in the file with below content.

```
the goof of the spoof
the horse of the sun
```

The bourne shell script is a.sh as below

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$1
grep $var file

>>sh a.sh 'the horse'
grep: can't open horse
file:the goof of the spoof
file:the horse of the sun
```

Please help me in this. 
So basically I want to know how to work if the user input parameters have space in between.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
var="$1"
grep "$var" file
```

When you keep in unquoted a space in `$var` makes shell interpret word before space as search pattern and word after space as the file it is searching in.